# org.json.jsonexception end of input at character 0 of android

Tags: android

```
public static String getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
            httppost.setHeader(
                    "Accept",
                    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json;q=0.9,/;q=0.8");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is my code  i am doing json parse using Httpget method when i try to parse then it show org.json.jsonexception end of input at character 0 of android and also in result blank value  i am getting while when i check from fiddler i am getting response i don't  know where am doing mistake please help me and suggest where am doing wrong .

Comment: Please read the logcat **cerfully** ... your `try-catch` blocks should be nested not parallel (obviously if `response.getEntity()` fails there is no sens to call rest of the code )

Comment: try {

   jArray = new JSONObject(result);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
  }  here exception coming please tell me what missing  here

Comment: you are missing basic logic skills: obviously `end of input at character 0` means that `result` is an empty string ... and it means that: response is an empty string ... or getting data from httpclient fails(there is an exception  in first or second `try-catch`) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open ur URl url  in device Browser if it will give response then ur service is ok there will missing in ur code if it will not give respnse there there is missing in server which is not giving response .